# Basic ruby code not working

Tags: ruby

I just learnt Ruby and I am doing some basic practise problems to get familiar with the language. I just came across this question:
"Write a method that takes an array of numbers. If a pair of numbers
in the array sums to zero, return the positions of those two numbers.
If no pair of numbers sums to zero, return nil."

This is my code:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  i = 0
  j = 0
  while i < nums.length
    while j < nums.length
      if nums[i] + nums[j] == 0
        return [i, j]
      end
      j+= 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return nil
end
```

It returns nil everytime. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You are correct. However, two_sum([1, 3, 5, -3]) returns nil. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`j` should be re-initialized to `0` when `i` gets incremented:

```
  while i < nums.length
    while j < nums.length
      if nums[i] + nums[j] == 0
        return [i, j]
      end
      j+= 1
    end
    i += 1
    j = 0   # Here
  end
```

Comment: @TejaK select it as an answer ; btw the lack of the `++` operator reminds me how silly Ruby is

Comment: @TejaK: Silly? Increment operators lead to a lot of confusion and ambiguity (just look at the number of questions about `++x + x++` and assorted silliness. It is understandable if you are making a language that is almost assembly, where `++` corresponds to `INC` and `+` to `ADD`; it makes little sense to single it out in a higher programming language. Also, `nums.each do |i|; nums.each do |y| ... end end` eliminate any need for manual incrementing. The code above runs on Ruby, but it is not Rubyish, and it is silly to make judgments on Ruby based on non-idiomatic code like that.

Comment: @Amadan I respectfully disagree.  Just because it was chosen not to include in the language does not mean it's a good decision.  JavaScript has it, does it make JavaScript confusing?  The reason not to include it over some of the things that were included for reason of clarity is nonsensical.  One day I believe Ruby will have it and we'll see if you're on the current bandwagon, or if that's how you truly feel; until then, I don't mind voicing an opinion against the grain, despite not being *Rubyish* because to me that's just *rubbish*.

Comment: @vol7ron: So far, nobody who has complained about the lack of an increment operator in Ruby has actually been able to come up with a working specification for one, despite claiming it would be easy. I'm sure if you can come up with a nice proposal, it would be considered.

Comment: @JörgWMittag These comments are turning into a conversation and don't apply to the answer above. I suspect we should communicate in some other way. -- To end it, I know I'm not the only one that has mentioned something and I don't care enough to pursue it. New Ruby coders are always surprised by this. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

While Yu Hao answers the literal question, here is a more Rubyish solution:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  nums.each_with_index do |x, i|
    j = nums.index(-x)
    return [i, j] if j
  end
  nil
end
```